# Can't read /usr/bin/bash in WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I wanted to apply WSL-2 Hacks as described here: https://github.com/shayne/wsl2-hacks
but when I try to edit /usr/bin/bash, I can only see lot of werids symbols and I do not know how to actually that... Other files looks normal. This is fresh ubuntu installation.

```
^?ELF^B^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@>^@^A^@^@^@0^D^C^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@X^G^R^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@8^@
```

^@@^@^^^@^]^@^F^@^@^@^D^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@�^B^@^@^@^@^@^@�^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^X^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^X^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^X^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@p�^B^@^@^@^@^@>
^@^@^@^@^@^@�
^@^@^@^@^@^@�
^@^@^@^@^@�a^C^@^@^@^@^@�a^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^F^@^@^@�L^Q^@^@^@^@^@�^Q^@^@^@^@^@�^Q^@^@^@^@^@^T�^@^@^@^@^@^@�U^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^F^@^@^@�u^Q^@^@^@^@^@��^Q^@^@^@^@^@��^Q^@^@^@^@^@^P^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^D^@^@^@8^C^@^@^@^@^@^@8^C^@^@^@^@^@^@8>
6^C^H�^H^S^H^ANL�^X@@@�A^DB^@
^P�0�I���q�(�^B^@^E^Fh^E^H      @^@�^@(^@��^LH ^[+^Q^D^@H&R^`^P^@D^@!^RD ^K^@^\�^@^D�^@ $DJ���^HP`^F
� ^D^C^P^V^F@A^E^P�4^P`�^H@^RAB^@^@f ^@L@^H^@^@�0 ^Ad�P�CDDB^Y�@�^V�^HE % ^C^P3^@2B�X�^T��^B@TB�^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H�^B�^PD$�^P^@  �^B^^�^B@^H @A^E^@^A�%^@ �^H^T^A^@^@^@^L^B�!^P0`0        ^@^@���^H�^D^@^H^@^@^H^H@^C@^@ �b�^P^AB^@^Qh^KHB�H^@��^[D^P�`1^@^AB�^B �Xq^A^@�^D@�^X^T^P^@�^\�^F^R �^@�Y ^AB^XdH^@�(^A0�^X^P"BB1^R@^C^@^@�^@^Lp�^H^@^@2^LI^Y^DP^C^@���^@^B�^P^P^D�8@^H^A s�0 ^U�"��B^Ti�^C$^H^N^P^Q^^^A�^T^D^B$^A^@DF�^@^X0"�BP^H^D� 6^@^A)4^P^@�^D���$ @^@^A�^@D��^AXI^T��^PAB�p^@ ^@^A@^F�B8: ^V^NBH^T��^P �^A�^X �&�� =^@�H^AdL@^A���0�(^P ^B0D@kB^ADQ��H`�$yh�^F�@(��>^U�5^@�R^T�����^B ^A�^F�^^B^A@!�^@%� P^EH�����

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to edit the bash *binary* (`/usr/bin/bash`).  That's like running `notepad C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` in Windows (don't do it).

You should be editing your Bash *startup configuration files*, which would typically be either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

> I wanted to apply WSL-2 Hacks

I personally recommend that you don't.  You appear to be new to Linux, and there's nothing wrong with that -- We all start there.  But running Systemd in WSL fundamentally alters WSL behavior in ways that you aren't going to expect.  I regularly come across questions and comments about something not working in WSL, and the answer all-too-often turns out to be that Systemd is in play.

Recommended reading:

- My [answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986), specifically, the section *"How to handle the lack of Systemd"*
- Jonathan Bowman's excellent blog post ["You Probably Don't Need systemd on WSL"](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/you-probably-don-t-need-systemd-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux-49gn)

If, after this, you still decide that you simply must have Systemd in WSL, consider [Distrod](https://github.com/nullpo-head/wsl-distrod) or [Genie](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie), which are more "prepackaged" solutions to Systemd on WSL.  However, please keep in mind the following at the top of the Genie doc:

> NOTE: Before you install genie for the first time, read ALL of this page. This will save you a great deal of trouble later on.